# file upload with ajax refreshes after upload

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am trying for file upload using ajax. Upload functionality is fine but page refreshes after file upload some reason. May be there is small issue which I am unable to find please some help me point it out. May be this question might turn out to be silly but mistake happens.

```
<form class="booking" id="addmovies" action="addmovies" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Movie Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mname" id="mname"/><span class="error1" id="merror"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Release Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker"/><span class="error1" id="dateerror"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Choose poster</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="poster"/><span class="error1" id="perror"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="ADD MOVIES" class="button_example"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<script>
$("#addmovies").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mname = $("#mname").val();
    var date = $("#datepicker").val();
    var poster = $("#poster").val();

    if (mname == "") {
        $("#merror").html("please enter the movie name");
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#merror").hide();
    }
    if (date == "") {
        $("#dateerror").html("please enter the date ");
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#dateerror").hide();
    }
    if (poster == "") {
        $("#perror").html("please choose the poster ");
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#perror").hide();
    }
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#message1").show().html("Uploading...");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#message1").html(data).fadeOut(5000);
            $("#movielist").load("movies");
            $("#mname").val("");
            $("#datepicker").val("");
            $("#poster").val("");
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$("#addmovies").on("submit", function(e) {
```

to:

```
$('#addmovies #submit').live('click', (function(e) {
```

or add `return false;`

```
$("#addmovies").on("submit", function(e) {
   //....
    $.ajax({
       //....
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: live is deprecated and on is the replacement for bind,live and delegate and off is replacement for unbind,die,undelegate

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return false;` to prevent the page from refreshing. Or you can add `event.preventDefault();` before your ajax call

Hope this helps

Comment: I already had event.preventDefault(); let me try return false